# How to upload multiple files in React-Redux

Tags: node.js, reactjs, file-upload, redux

I had a query that I wanted to ask you about. I was building an application in React-Redux with Express NodeJS as backend, and postgreSQL as db. I wanted to implement a File Upload component into it. Can you please tell me how should I do that ?

Our team had previously implemented file upload in angular using multer on the backend. When we did the same in redux the small files get uploaded fine but when I try to upload a file over 4 mb it re-renders the page before the file is completely uploaded.

Please guide me how should I do this ? If you have a code sample that I can understand, that will also be great.

Comment: Uday, You'll need to throw up some more information to get a good answer. The first of which is how are you uploading the file? i.e. What solution are you using for API access?

Comment: Also are you using the three stage pattern for api access in redux? Request/Success/Failure

Comment: I had used AXIOS to send requests! and yes I am using 3 stage pattern. But could you suggest me something from the beginning ? Something I can follow entirely from scratch ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to upload multiple files at once in React.

```
<input type="file" multiple 
 name="myImage" accept=".png, .jpeg" className="multiple-upload" 
 onChange={this.uploadScreenshotFile} />
```

Here is uploadScreenshotFile function

```
uploadScreenshotFile(event){
    for(let size=0; size < event.target.files.length; size++){
      console.log('Selected file:', event.target.files[size]);
      let file = event.target.files[size];
      console.log("uploading screenshot file...");

      // Do necessary request to upload here.......

    }
}
```

Comment: my main concern is uploading a file and handling it at backend. Can you guide me in that respect ?!

Comment: I have not ever tried upload file with Node.js. May be this article will be useful for you:
1. https://medium.com/technoetics/handling-file-upload-in-nodejs-7a4bb9f09a27
2. https://dzone.com/articles/upload-files-or-images-to-server-using-nodejs

Comment: thanks Harsh. I did actually use that article earlier and it was successful. Technoetics one. It implemented File Upload in React and NodeJS !